# The Sum of Geometric-Factorial Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I was pondering over my *Sequences & Series* homework, when the following series struck my mind:

> $0!+1!x+2!x^{2}+3!x^{3}+.......+n!x^{n}$

And believe me, I am serious that I couldn't think of any approach, but it looked beautiful.I tried to look up all possible summation methods, but it seemed like they didn't offer a break to me.  So guys, any ideas or approach?

Comment: There is an awful closed form for $x=1$ (With an added $1$) https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html But I don’t think it will have a nice form in general

Comment: Is the first term meant to be $0!$ instead of $0!x$?

Comment: The suggested polynomial is a type of Left Factorial polynomial. Left Factorials are fun to learn about and rarely spotted in the wild. An example of some classes of Left Factorial polynomials may be found in the paper [Generalized Factorial Functions, Numbers and Polynomials](http://www.mi.sanu.ac.rs/~gvm/radovi/MB-16-113-130.pdf)

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for noticing, edited :)

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks for the pointer, will check 'em out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not so bad if you are aware of the incomplete gamma function since
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n k! \,x^k$$
$$f_n(x)=-\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x}\Bigg[(-1)^n (n+1)!\, \Gamma \left(-(n+1),-\frac{1}{x}\right)+\Gamma
   \left(0,-\frac{1}{x}\right) \Bigg]$$ For $x=1$ appears the subfactorial functions and, for $x>1$ the exponential integral function.

Comment: Whoa! Looks nice, but could you elaborate? Since I am not aware of the incomplete gamma function :(

Comment: @PrateekPKulkarni; It is nice if you plan to line your wall with it ! Otherwise, it is ugly. Don't  worry : you will learn about it soon. Meanwhile, have a tour at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function